# Vimeo API Integration

Tags: php, api, vimeo

I am trying to create a site that uses the viemo api to search for videos and then output them in xml format. I was off to a good start but now I am stuck. The user input is posting but no results are showing up on the firebug console...

Here is my .php for the vimeo api integration:

```
    <?
include('connect.php');

$video_id= $_POST['text'];

$url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2';
$url .= '?';
$url .= 'method=vimeo.videos.search&';
$url .= 'oauth_consumer_key='.$api_key2.'&';
$url .= 'per_page=10&';
$url .= 'query='.$video_id.'&';
$url .= 'sort=relevant&';
$url .= 'full_response=1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($curl_response);

$title= 'title';
$id = 'id';
$video_url = 'videosurl';
$thumbnails = 'thumbnail[1]';
$outputXML .= "";

$outputXML .= "<rsp>\n";

foreach($xmlObject->videos as $video) {
    $videoTagBegin = "\t<video>\n";
    $urlXML = "\t\t<videosurl>".$video->attributes()->$video_url."</videosurl>\n";
    $titleXML = "\t\t<title>".$video->attributes()->$title."</title>\n";
    $thumbXML = "\t\t<thumbnail>".$video->attributes()->$thumbnails."</thumbnail>\n";
    $videoTagEnd = "\t</video>\n";
    $outputXML .= $videoTagBegin.$titleXML.$thumbXML.$urlXML.$videoTagEnd;
}
$outputXML .= "</rsp>";

print $outputXML;

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am completely stuck.

This is my JS if it helps at all....

```
function closeDivs(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('').empty();
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#searchbtn').bind('click' || 'enter',function(e) {
        if ($.trim($('#searchBox').val()) !== '') {
            $('#videos').empty();
            closeDivs(e);
            $('#videos').append('<img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading" />');
            getEvents(e);
            getVideos(e);
        }
    });

function getEvents(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = 'event_id='+$('#searchBox').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getEvents.php',
        dataType: 'xml',
        type: 'POST',
        data: text,
        success: function(data) {                   
            },

        error: function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }

    })
};

function getVideos(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = 'video_id='+$('#searchBox').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getVideos.php',
        dataType: 'xml',
        type: 'POST',
        data: text,
        success: function(data) {                               

        },
        error: function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }

    })
};
});
```

Comment: are you getting anything in curl_response

Comment: No. In firebug nothing is displayed except that the user input was posted. It does say Error: [object Object]. But that is it.

Comment: Could it be a authorization problem?? I have been very confused about the OAuth stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are getting nothing back from curl 
try amening your code like this to see if there are any errors

```
if($curl_response===false)
{
    exit('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
```

before you close the curl call - to see what is going on

Comment: nothing comes up when i add that, but now firebug is showing that <rsp></rsp> is writing in XML but nothing else.

Comment: i can give you the link to project if that helps solve the problem, lol

Comment: what does curl_reponse contain if you echo it?

Comment: echo the url out and paste it in a terminal as such: curl <url>  or a browser and see what you get - there is obviously a problem with your call - you may be right about oauth but I think you should still get a response

Comment: ok this is what the url echo response was: http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?method=vimeo.videos.search&oauth_consumer_key=89d0e33d0bd6ee92302a1023c14f1758&per_page=10&query=&sort=relevant&full_response=1          <rsp>
</rsp>

Comment: I also did echo $curl_reponse and got this error.... <rsp generated_in="0.0099" stat="fail">
  <err code="400" expl="A required parameter was missing: oauth_timestamp." msg="Missing required parameter"/>